# right join even if row on second table does not exist

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to join two tables even if there is no match on the second one.

table user:

```
uid | name
1     dude1
2     dude2
```

table account:

```
uid | accountid | name
1     1           account1
```

table i want:

```
uid  | username | accountname
1      dude1      account1
2      dude2      NULL
```

the query i'm trying with:

```
SELECT user.uid as uid, user.name as username, account.name as accountname
FROM user RIGHT JOIN account ON user.uid=accout.uid
```

what i'm getting:

```
uid  | username | accountname
1      dude1      account1
```

Comment: Use a LEFT JOIN.

Comment: Lol... avalanche of "left join" answers.

Comment: left join worked! i must have done something wrong when i tried before.. now which answer do I mark as correct? :p

Comment: the one who answer first.. order them by "oldest"

Answer (score 38, accepted):

use `Left Join` instead

```
SELECT user.uid as uid, user.name as username, account.name as accountname
FROM user LEFT JOIN account ON user.uid=account.uid
```

Answer (score 5):

Try with a `LEFT JOIN` query

```
SELECT user.uid as uid, user.name as username, account.name as accountname
FROM user 
LEFT JOIN account 
ON user.uid=accout.uid
```

I'd like you have a look at this visual representation of [**`JOIN`** query](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Answer (score 5):

Right join keeps all results from the 2nd table (it keeps all results on the right-hand table), you want a left join, or swap the positions of user and account in the join clause.

```
SELECT user.uid as uid, user.name as username, account.name as accountname
FROM user LEFT JOIN account ON user.uid=account.uid
```

I believe that should do it.

Comment: `user` is not a reserved keyword in mysql http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html